# How to do socket programming in a django app

Tags: python, django, sockets, web-applications

I have a Django web application which shows a website to display some data. So, this application consists of the html pages and views to display this data which i am storing in a SQLite DB.

At the end of the day a **third party needs to connect to this web application and upload binary data over to the application**. *What is the best way to host this service, as an independent python web server or part of Django application or how else ?*

Any suggestions would be appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

If the uploading doesn't occur too often, why not just create a Django `POST`/`PUT` view for the job that simply accepts the file over HTTP? With the information you've provided, I cannot see why this simple solution wouldn't be up to the task.

Comment: Hi Erik, Thanks for your comment. That is an option, but the problem is that the THIRD PARTY sends some what complex binary data and is programmed to connect to a TCP port and send data. And changing it is not in our hands.

Comment: If it's just an occasional incoming TCP connection, just go with an extra process to do the listening and handling, which then for example triggers a notification to the HTTP layer about the new file it's just received. Or something like that... And you can obviously choose to use stuff like Gevent or Twisted or whatnot in that extra process.